# Reading the json file correctly

Tags: pandas

This statement reads the json file. But it does not split the columns correctly.

df = pd.read_json('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/config1.json', orient='index')

Is there any way to read the json using pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json.json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('config1.json') as f:    
    data = json.load(f)  

df = json_normalize(data, 'configurationItems', ['fileVersion'])
print (df)
                                                 ARN  awsAccountId  awsRegion  \
0  arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-1:513469704633:trai...  513469704633  us-east-1   
1  arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-1:513469704633:trai...  513469704633  us-east-1   

  configurationItemCaptureTime configurationItemStatus  \
0     2018-07-27T11:52:53.795Z         ResourceDeleted   
1     2018-07-27T11:52:53.791Z         ResourceDeleted   

  configurationItemVersion  configurationStateId configurationStateMd5Hash  \
0                      1.3         1532692373795                             
1                      1.3         1532692373791                             

  relatedEvents relationships                 resourceId  \
0            []            []  AWSMacieTrail-DO-NOT-EDIT   
1            []            []                     test01   

             resourceType supplementaryConfiguration tags fileVersion  
0  AWS::CloudTrail::Trail                         {}   {}         1.0  
1  AWS::CloudTrail::Trail                         {}   {}         1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
import json
import urllib.request as req
import pandas as pd

with req.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/config1.json") as j:
    raw = json.loads(j.read().decode())

df = pd.DataFrame(raw["configurationItems"])
df["fileVersion"] = raw["fileVersion"]

print(df)
```